# Gyp precompiled headers for xcode

Tags: precompiled-headers, gyp

How do you specify precompiled headers for xcode with gyp, specifically xcode 4.6 with clang.

I only see visual studio options.

```
'msvs_precompiled_header': 'stdio.h',
'msvs_precompiled_source': 'precomp.c',
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gyp is pretty nice but the documentation is awful.

The answer in case anyone runs across the need for it is:

```
'xcode_settings': {
  'GCC_PREFIX_HEADER': 'path/from/gyp/file/to/header.h',
  'GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER': 'YES',
},
```

Also worth noting you can set pretty much everything in this page in a xcode_settings block

[Xcode Build Settings Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html)