# Precompiled headers in node-gyp (linux)

Tags: g++, node-gyp, precompiled-headers, gyp

Looking for information about precompiled headers, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32501048/12750353) post for windows, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16065543/12750353) for xcode. But I didn't find an example for linux.

How can I make use of precompiled headers for compilation speedup?